# Regex multiline log

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I'd like to use a .NET / Powershell regex to search a log for `Success` status at a particular location, say `ABC`.

If I use the following pattern: `"(?ms)A status: Success.*?Location: "` with global (aka AllMatches) then it finds all log record with a status of `Success` at any location.

If I try to narrow it down by appending `ABC` to the pattern, then the match is too greedy and goes from the Success on line 18 all the way to the `ABC` on line 28.

I gave up and used a pattern that is more explicit (it grabs the full log record and seems to work because I specify a pattern between Success and Location):

`(?sm)^\d([ \S]*\s{10}){3}A status: Success\s{2}([ \S]*\s{10}){2}Location: ABC[ \S]*`

Is there a simpler pattern which can find what I'm after?

Note: I don't mind if the pattern grabs the full log record from date time (inclusive) to date time (exclusive),

Log file:

```
04/09/2018 06:31:59 AM [class | Info] some message received from 101592 (123.123.123.124)
        Request Id: 0 (Descriptor: 0, Operator Request Id: 0)
        A type: bar
        A status: Queued
        The id: 1E25
        Additional info: Inserted in queue at position 1 on device ABC
        Location: ABC, subarea: 2
04/09/2018 06:31:59 AM [class | Info] some message received from 102364 (123.123.123.123)
        Request Id: 0 (Descriptor: 0, Operator Request Id: 0)
        A type: bar
        A status: Queued
        The id: 1E25
        Additional info: Inserted in queue at position 1 on device ABC
        Location: ABC, subarea: 2
04/09/2018 06:31:59 AM [class | Info] some message received from 102364 (123.123.123.123)
        Request Id: 0 (Descriptor: 0, Operator Request Id: 0)
        A type: blah bit foo
        A status: Success
        The id: T908
        Additional info: 
        Location: DEF, subarea: 3
04/09/2018 06:32:00 AM [class | Info] some message received from 102364 (123.123.123.123)
        Request Id: 0 (Descriptor: 0, Operator Request Id: 0)
        A type: bar
        A status: Success
        The id: DG08
        Additional info: 
        Location: ABC, subarea: 1
```

Comment: A [single regex](https://regex101.com/r/vXscse/1) approach is rather cumbersome here.

Comment: Read the file using `Get-Content -Raw`, split into blocks at `"(?m)^(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})"` and use `Where-Object` or `Select-String` repeatedly to filter down on the blocks you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with any of these:

`(?m)A status: Success(?:\n\h+.+)+Location: ABC`

`(?m)A status: Success(?:\n\s+.+)+Location: ABC` (if `\h` is not supported)

**[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/0NcGrm/4/)**

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/0NcGrm/5/)**

**Explained**:

Just limit the way you process extra data. Instead of a `.*?`, just use `(?:\n\h+[^\n]+)+` (that is new line + some spaces at the beginning) That will disallow going through the next log entry, since the date starts at the begining of the line.

(NOTE: I deleted the `s` modifier)

Comment: Your regex only works, if the desired log entry is the overall last entry.

Comment: @SebastianProske Totally right. It should be fixed now. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think .NET supports the \h (horizontal whitespace) escape character but otherwise is OK.

Comment: It can be changed by a `\s` I just used `\h` to be safer. I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `^\d{2}\/(.++\n){3}(?=.+Success)(.++\n){3}(?=.+ABC).++`.

I start a match, if at the beginning of the line there are two digits followed by `/`: `^\d{2}\/`.

Then, I match three lines, to go into `status` line: `(.++\n){3}`, I used possessive quantifier to avoid backtracking.

Then I match next three lines if `Success` occurs on current line (I check that with positive lookahead): `(?=.+Success)(.++\n){3}`.

Then I match last line, if there is `ABC` in that line: `(?=.+ABC).++`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/geg83b/1)